# Allow question-based chat earlier

Tags: feature-request, chat

When a user is having trouble with an answer, a comment conversation goes on for a while, then SO prompts you to head to chat. However, this option only happens after enough comments have been applied.

When a user is clearly in the weeds (after a just a few comments) it would be nice if we could immediately choose the "Go to chat" option, or perhaps have an obvious way to set one up on the chat site itself. When I looked, it appeared as if creating a new room was for general topics, and there was no way to create one of the "question-based" rooms.

Could we make this process a little easier?

Comment: Agreed: `"add a comment" "join chat"` perhaps a count of the current question chatters also

Comment: @Dagon The question chatter count is a good idea, and the first user to join chat should probably have an auto-comment with a link to the chat room (similar to what already exists).

Comment: chat contents is lost when its finished, since it may of actually answered the question it would be good if it could be recorded and then posted back to the question - or am i making this to difficult :-)

Comment: @Dagon I would think that the initiating user (presumably the poster) should have the onus of editing relevant information into the question/answer. Chats get *really* long, I wouldn't want that put into a post or comment string.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I'd like to see this implemented.

Comment: Would probably avoid a lot of garbage.

Comment: It would be nice to have markup for a chat invite: `[chat]Let's chat about this[/chat]` -- creates a hyperlink to a post-related chat, "Conversation regarding post #1234"

Comment: _chat contents is lost when its finished_ Is it? At the top it says Chat is persistent. At the bottom of the man page it says that Chats will persist when and if they have at least 15 posts. This could definitely use an overhaul!